# How do I read a CSV file into my local Oracle Database table?

Tags: java, oracle, csv

My goal is to read from a CSV file, loading it into a sample database table (Oracle) that I have .
So far , I have the following Java code :

```
    public class ParsingCSV {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

        ParsingCSV obj = new ParsingCSV();
        obj.run();

      }

        @SuppressWarnings("oracle.jdeveloper.java.nested-assignment")
        public void run() {

        String csvFile = "C:\\Users\\IBM_ADMIN\\Desktop\\Work\\ConnectOne_Bancorp\\Database_Work\\Book1.csv";
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line = "";
        String cvsSplitBy = ",";

        try {

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                    // use comma as separator
                String[] country = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

                System.out.println("Country [code= " + country[4] 
                                     + " , name=" + country[5] + "]");

            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
/* boilerplate */
```

any tips/pointers appreciated , thanks !

Comment: What's the question?  I'm not seeing anything that tries to write the data to a table.  i'm not seeing anything that specifies how the data from the file maps to the columns in the table.  Why are you writing Java for this in the first place?  Could you use SQL*Loader instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tips could be:

1. Download the Oracle Database driver  [Oracle driver](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html)
2. Set the .jar to your classpath. [java setting class path]
3. Register the driver and connect to the database [java connect to oracle]
4. Execute sql "CREATE TABLE...." [sql create table example]
5. For every line that you read do sql = "INSERT INTO..." [sql insert into example]

For every step if you need more example and advice, I suggest google use the [] tags to search